# AngularJs currency in Euro

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple question.
In my application, I have to show a currency.

`{{money | currency: "EUR"}}`

but it shows in this way: `EUR 27,272.02`
Is there any way to in correct Euro format? I want to have `EUR 27.272,02`

Thanks.

Comment: Speaking as an American, that *looks* correct.  You're probably looking for a localization display instead.

Comment: how can comma come after dot?

Comment: Becuase In euro dot split thousands and comma splits with cents... I know in US is different, but In euro you write currency like 12.532,00

Comment: This is the correct formatting for euros

Comment: Yes, it was a duplicate and I fix it using that post as guide line.

Comment: I just used this link  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.6.6/angular-locale_it.js and save it as internal js file. It worked!